# AS2 Adding variable to loop

Tags: loops, variables, actionscript

I am new to this forum so be gentle!

In actionscript 2, I have a series of movieclips call "target+number", within a movieclip called "large_mc".

They each have a unique x value which is added via this loop:

```
for (i = 0; i<= 5; i++){
large_mc["target"+i].id = i}
```

Each "target" movieclip includes a text field called "_txt" whose propertues I can alter individually like this;

```
large_mc.target1._txt.background=true; large_mc.target1._txt.borderColor=0x000033;`
```

etc

My question is how to do this using a loop

My difficulty is including the variable "i".

I have tried things like

```
for (i = 0; i<= 5; i++){
large_mc["target"+i]_txt.background=true}
```

but not successfully.

I think there is a simple solution, I just cant work out the grammar!

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dot(.) at end of the square brackets

> large_mc["target"+i]

```
 for (i = 0; i<= 5; i++)
 {
   large_mc["target"+i]._txt.background=true
 }
```